# Increment IP address in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, loops, ip

It is possible to write this script in another way to increment ip address whitout loops like this? Script, a port scanner, works fine and mine is only a question about efficiency. Sorry for my english and thanks for your answers.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip=$1
IFS=. read i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< "$ip"  
port=$2
max=255

   while [ $i1 -le $max ];do
       while [ $i2 -le $max ]; do 
            while [ $i3 -le $max ]; do
                  while [ $i4 -le $max ]; do
                     timeout 0.4 bash -c "echo >/dev/tcp/$i1.$i2.$i3.$i4/$port" && echo "on $i1.$i2.$i3.$i4  port $port is open" 
                      i4=$(($i4+1)) 
                  done
            i4=0
            i3=$(($i3+1))
            done
       i3=0
       i2=$(($i2+1))
       done
   i2=0
   i1=$(($i1+1))
   done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
i1=0; i2=0; i3=0; i4=0
max=255
eval printf -v ip "%s\ " {$i1..$max}.{$i2..$max}.{$i3..$max}.{$i4..$max}

for i in $ip; do
  # do here somthing with $i
done
```

Comment: there is a way to put in column in a text file the output of eval command?

Comment: Did you mean something like that? `for i in $ip; do echo "$i"; done`

Comment: yes but in this case we will utilize another loop scheme from while to for. eval is interesting function thanks but how can i  manipulate the output element by element ?because  script you posted gave me a complete output flow. thanks for your time cyrus

Answer (score 13):

This function just prints next ip:

```
nextip(){
    IP=$1
    IP_HEX=$(printf '%.2X%.2X%.2X%.2X\n' `echo $IP | sed -e 's/\./ /g'`)
    NEXT_IP_HEX=$(printf %.8X `echo $(( 0x$IP_HEX + 1 ))`)
    NEXT_IP=$(printf '%d.%d.%d.%d\n' `echo $NEXT_IP_HEX | sed -r 's/(..)/0x\1 /g'`)
    echo "$NEXT_IP"
}
```

So you can increment it like:

```
FIRST_IP=192.168.1.250
NUM=10

IP=$FIRST_IP
for i in $(seq 1 $NUM); do
    echo $IP
    IP=$(nextip $IP)
done
```

Sample output:

```
192.168.1.250
192.168.1.251
192.168.1.252
192.168.1.253
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.255
192.168.2.0
192.168.2.1
192.168.2.2
192.168.2.3
```